# Network Analyst not working

Tags: esri-geodatabase, arcgis-9.3, routing, network-analyst

I have network analyst installed as an extension in my arcGIS 9.3, but it just does not work!!! when I go to ArcCatalog, the option of new network data set also does not appear... :( I have to do this job of finding routes & I need this to work. I am zero at programming & I don't have arc server as well.

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: yes... That's licensed...

Comment: have you added the extension, you need to go to extensions I think it is under tools in the menu and tick the box, you have to do it seperately in both catalog and arcmap

Comment: @Sunil: No it is not enabled as yet...

Comment: @banger: I did it the same way as U have mentioned dude... still not enabled.

Comment: @sunil, my dear I told you that I have tried but there seems some issues God knows what... To my experience, It should, but its just not working... drop down menu opens but options are not enabled.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7768/discussion-between-user12648-and-sunil)

Comment: do you need to create a dataset first, then create the geometric network inside the dataset?

Comment: @banger: I suppose that's the only way I know... never worked with this thing before and taking help online... :)

Comment: @Sunil: snapshots have been added... its how this behaves in catalog and ArcMap... hope its helpful... :)

Comment: @Sunil: Thanks a lot buddy... :) I am still not able to make it... I suppose there is some license issue else this had been done by now... :( Ill get another copy of Arc & then try or use some alternate for this...

Comment: @user12648 looks like you are using wi-fi connection so might be license issue I guess..

Comment: @user12648 Recommend you to download ArcGIS DT 10.1 60 days trial copy and use it for 60 days..

Comment: thx bro doing the same... yes it seem to have license issues...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So here is what I would Find out:

1. Is your License valid, and not expired? To see this go to Start>>ArcGIS>>Desktop Administrator and go to the Availability Section. You will see how many ArcGIS Network Analyst extension licenses are available on your License Server, and how many are free. It will also indicate the expiry date of the License.
2. In ArcCatalog go to Tools>>Extensions, and see if you have checked out the License for the Network Analyst. This needs to be done before you can use any Network Analyst Tools.

Comment: thx a lot for the kind help... :)

Comment: did it solve your issue?

Comment: yes it was a helpful answer... :) thx...

Comment: Please consider marking it as accepted, if this solved your issue.

Comment: Oh that... My apologies... I thought Its done now... :) since I am new to this site... :)

Comment: You need to click on the Check Mark next to my answer, to mark it as accepted. And no Apologies Needed. ;-) We all have to begin somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can watch this link. Network Analyst options will be activated after following certain steps on setting up the problem.
http://video.arcgis.com/watch/2109/creating-network-datasets-cost-attributes-and-evaluators

Answer (score 0):

have you gone to the ESRI help pages yet
http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=An_overview_of_Network_Analyst
sorry if you have already tried it, but it's always a good place to start